# Javascript click event listener function not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make an event listener for generating a random round number but it doesn't seem to be working.I have added an event listener to the guess id but nothing is working.

Here is my javascript. In this section I try to add a click event listener to the "guess" id and generate a random number using the generateTarget function

```js
let humanScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let currentRoundNumber = 1;

// Write your code below:
const generateTarget = () => Math.random * 10

const compareGuesses = (human, computer, generateTarget) => Math.abs(human - generateTarget) > Math.abs(computer - generateTarget)

document.getElementById("guess").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("target-number").innerHTML = generateTarget()
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Number Guesser</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="game-container">
    <header>
      <h1>Number Guesser!</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="rounds">
      <p class="round-label">Round <span id="round-number">1</span></p>
      <p class="guess-label">Target Number: <span id="target-number">?</span></p>=
    </div>

    <div class="guessing-area">
      <div class="guess computer-guess">
        <div class="guess-title">
          <p class="guess-label">Computer</p>
          <p class="score-label">Score: <span id="computer-score">0</span></p>
        </div>
        <p id="computer-guess">?</p>
        <p class="winning-text" id="computer-wins"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="guess human-guess">
        <div class="guess-title">
          <p class="guess-label">You</p>
          <p class="score-label">Score: <span id="human-score">0</span></p>
        </div>
        <input type="number" id="human-guess" min=0 max=9 value=0>
        <div class="number-controls">
          <button class="number-control left" id="subtract" disabled>-</button>
          <button class="number-control right" id="add">+</button>
        </div>
        <button class="button" id="guess">Make a Guess</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="next-round-container">
      <button class="button" id="next-round" disabled>Next Round</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="instructions">
    <div class="instruction">
      <h3>Step 1</h3>
      <p>Input a number between 0 and 9</p>
    </div>
    <div class="instruction">
      <h3>Step 2</h3>
      <p>Click "Make a Guess" to submit your guess and see who won the round.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="instruction">
      <h3>Step 3</h3>
      <p>Click "Next Round" to play again.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
  <script src="./game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Typo: `Math.random` should be `Math.random()`

Comment: You might also want to convert to an integer, otherwise the player has practically no chance of guessing all the digits after the decimal point.